# Why I can not print NULL address in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Let's say that I have a Linked list class as follows.

```cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* rptr;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node* curr;
    Node* prev;
    Node* first;
    Node node;

    LinkedList()
    {
        curr = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
        first = NULL;
        node.data = NAN;
        node.rptr = NULL;
    }

    void push(int);
    void pop();
};

void LinkedList::push(int data) 
{
    curr = new Node;
    curr->data = data;
    curr->rptr = NULL;

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        prev = first = curr;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->rptr = curr;
        curr->data = data;
        prev = curr;
    }


}

void LinkedList::pop()
{
    Node* temp = NULL;
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        cout << "No more Data Element\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << first->data<<'\n';
        temp = first;
        first = first->rptr;
        cout << first->rptr << endl;//error on this line
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

And my main as follows

```cpp
int main()
{
    LinkedList l1;

    l1.push(10);
    l1.push(20);
    l1.push(30);
    l1.pop();
    l1.pop();
    l1.pop();
    l1.pop();
    l1.pop();
}
```

My question is when I try to print the address with NULL, it gives me an exception. Is there any way I can print it, because it is printing other addresses fine but not this NULL one.

We can easily see in Python if we assign None to something and print it. So does C++ has same feature or not?

Comment: Please read [*Programming in C++*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/), the documentation of your C or C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)...) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Avoid [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) such as [segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). For your next question, provide some [mre].

Comment: if `x` is a null ptr then `x->rdata` is not allowed. I dont think  this is any different in python

Comment: as the answer explains, the real problem is not that you are printing the value of a `nullptr`. Try `int * x = 0; std::cout << x;` to see what happens when you do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is, that you did not try to print a `nullptr`, but you access it and want to print the result. Before you get the result to print, your program already has a null pointer exception which is totally unrelated to printing.

```
first = first->rptr;
```

`first` is a valid pointer ( not nullptr ) and you assign `first` now with what is content of `rptr`. In your case, the value of `first->rptr` is `nullptr`.

And if you try to `first->rptr` again, you want to get the value from where first points to which is impossible.

You already check before that `first` is valid ( not nullptr ) but after getting the new value, you don't.

BTW: You should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` if you want to assign a pointer a "0" or compare against this.